# How can I view the production meteor log?

Tags: meteor

Is there a way I can view the server side logs of a Meteor application in production? My deployed app (myapp.meteor.com) is throwing an 'Internal Server Error' so I need to view the server log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the meteor command line tool:

```
meteor logs myapp.meteor.com
```

Comment: this works only if the app run on Meteor Galaxy. What about custom servers ?

Comment: Actually, this q&a predates Galaxy.  Custom servers will have a custom solution....  check the script that starts the server.